# Entity Relationship diagram with 2 independent entities

Tags: entity-relationship

Can there exist an Entity Relationship Diagram containing 2 independent entities with no relation between them?

Comment: And why would you need such ER diagram , without relation between two? It may be non practical but it can exist.

Comment: I have developed a search engine with 3 tables-Ranking(SeriaL_No.,Rank,Url),Indexing(Serial_No.,Url,Domain,Sub_domain,An‌​chor_Text,Page_Title,Keywords) and Categories(Category,Keywords),So the E-R Diagram will contain 3 independent entities,there will be no relationship amongst them.Is this ER Diagram correct?

Comment: Why would you need an ER diagram? There are no joins, no dependencies, no normalization(2NF+). If you want to creating any UML diagram, and there is an ER diagram without R, I would suggest you to go with class diagram.

Answer (score 0):

No there cannot exist a ER diagram containing two independent entities. Basically the point of an ER diagram is to show how the entities are related and the basic schema of the database. Do you have an issue with an ER diagram that you are trying to create?

Comment: I have developed a search engine with 3 tables-Ranking(SeriaL_No.,Rank,Url),Indexing(Serial_No.,Url,Domain,Sub_domain,Anchor_Text,Page_Title,Keywords) and Categories(Category,Keywords),So the E-R Diagram will contain 3 independent entities,there will be no relationship amongst them.Is this ER Diagram correct?

Comment: Post an image of the diagram that you have created and I can work with you to correct it.